# Is there a way to read NFC tag id from background dispatch without opening activity?

Tags: android, nfc

I am looking to read the ID of any tag detected by the user in background, without actually opening an activity in my app.
What I currently have is an intent-filter for TECH_DISCOVERED in my MainActivity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
   android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

where `nfc_tech_filter.xml` defines all the technologies I want. It works as expected, the activity is either opened directly or the user is required to choose between different apps. Is it possible to get limited data about the tag, such as the ID, without any user interaction?

Comment: What are you expecting to process the data from the Tag? Do you really mean that you want to process the Tag ID in the background when your App is running with one of it's Activities is in the foreground?

Comment: @Andrew Not really, I use foreground dispatch for that. I'm questioning whether there is a way to receive an intent in one of my activities with partial/full information from a Tag that was scanned outside my app. With the implementation from above, I only receive an Intent when the activity is opened either automatically or when the user chooses to do so. I don't want to open my activity nor ask the user for it, just process the data.

Comment: If you don't want to open your activity then you have no process running therefore, there is nothing running to process the data, you are asking the impossible. You have to have your App running for the data to be processed, either it was started running by the system or already running.

Comment: The app is running in background, perhaps I can receive such intents/data in my background Service? The processing is done in the service as well as showing a notification when this happens, but can it listen for NFC reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really NFC's security model is NFC is only handled in the foreground, this matches the logic that if the user has brought the NFC Tag in to range then they are expecting some interaction with it and to do that the App has to be in the foreground.

There a various different ways to start what might be termed "background Service", they all have limitation and they still might be stopped by the system and Google have changed what is supported over time and there was a large set of changes in Android 8.

The android code that handles NFC has various checks to make sure NFC is only handled by a foreground App.